# OS X El Capitan 10.11.3, need explanation of Console message

Tags: macos, mac, console

Can anyone give me an idea what exactly does this mean a message in my console:

```
symptoms: -[NetworkAnalyticsEngine_writeJournalRecord:fromCellFingerprint:key:atL0I:ofKind:lqm:isFaulty
```

Also this:

```
starting airdrop server for user 501 wake
```

This happened when computer was asleep and Wi-Fi was disabled.

Comment: It looks like it tried to wake up and use wifi, but it was disabled so something failed.  Has this reoccurred?